Why does the Solovay-Kitaev theorem use the operator norm?
In this review explaining the Solovay-Kitaev theorem, it is stated that the theorem uses the operator norm to define closeness between unitaries. This is then used to determine if a particular set of gates is universal. That is, we require the condition
$$d(U,S) := \sup _{\|\psi\|=1}\|(U-S) \psi\|<\epsilon$$
to decide if the unitary $S$ we constructed from our gate set is a good approximation of the desired unitary $U$.
My question is - why is the operator norm the right choice here? Shouldn't one consider a notion like the diamond distance where we consider the action of $U$ and $S$ on entangled states and see if those outputs are close?

Why is there "Solovay-Kitaev" in your title? The question seems about the difference/relation between operator and diamond norm, or when one can use the former.

I have edited to add the detail. The linked review paper explaining the Solovay-Kitaev theorem states that the theorem uses the operator norm to define closeness between unitaries. This is then used to determine if a particular set of gates is universal. I don't understand why the operator norm is sufficient

See my answer: There is no difference to the diamond norm in the setting where the map is acting on the Hilbert space rather than as a superoperator.

For a linear map $A$ on the Hilbert space (e.g., $A=U-S$), the two norms are equivalent -- they merely differ by a square.
This is a simple exercise, using that the norm which is maximized over all density operators $\rho$ in the diamond norm is convex in $\rho$ (due to the triangle inequality), and thus acquired its maximum on pure states -- for which the trace norm (which is maximized in the diamond norm) and the Hilbert space $2$-norm (which is maximized in the operator norm) are identical (up to a square).

Could you give me a reference for the 2-norm and 1-norm being related by a square? I am only aware of the bound $|v|_1 \geq |v|_2 \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|v|_1$ where $n$ is the dimension of the vectors $v_i$ (from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000173/bound-on-l1-norm-given-bound-on-l2-norm)

@user290109 the statement is about norms on different vector spaces: we have that $| (A\otimes\mathbb{1})|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|(A\otimes\mathbb{1})^\dagger|1 = | (A\otimes\mathbb{1})\psi|{\ell_2}^2$ because we're computing the trace norm of a rank one operator. Maximizing the latter expression over $\psi$ yields the operator norm $|A\otimes\mathbb{1}|\infty^2=| A |\infty^2$.

@MarkusHeinrich thank you - Is the last equality because the operator norm of the tensor product is the product of the operator norms?

@user290109 Yes, indeed.
